# Canvas.drawLine() how to get smooth line?

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing, line

Im trying to create a smooth line using Canvas.drawLine() and saving it to bitmap.
This is the code Im using

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3.5f);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
```

What I get is this

[image: Blurry]

But instead I would like to get something like this

[image: Not blurry]

Comment: replace `y1` value with  `y2` value like this : `canvas.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y1, paint);`

Comment: Line angle isnt the problem.

Comment: The stroke width is in pixels. Your images show lines that are much larger than 3.5 pixels wide. You appear to be scaling up the image when viewing it, however you're doing that.